# StreamWriter crashes with large text files in C#

Tags: c#, file, text, streamwriter

I am using StreamWriter to write to a file. When I use a text with 10-50 word text, it works properly. However when i call the function again (it exceeds the 50 words) it crashes. Why is this happening? Any suggestions?

Here is the codes:

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("text6.txt");
file.Close();

        int count = 0;
        string temp = "";
        string temp2 = "";

        for (Match m = Regex.Match(str, qmatch2); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
        {
            temp = m.Value;
            temp2 = Regex.Replace(temp, qmatch2, " . ");
            str = Regex.Replace(str, temp, temp2);
        }

if (temp.Contains(".") == false)
            {
                file = File.AppendText("text6.txt");
                file.WriteLine(" " + temp);
                count++;
                file.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Do you have a code example which produces the problem you speak of?

Comment: Have you wrapped the StreamWriter in a try/catch block? What exception is being thrown?

Comment: "exceeds the 50 words" - that is not 'large'

Comment: it is giving an IO exception, i will put my code in a sec.

Comment: Okay better to start from the beginning after seeing that code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you have a read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help then have a go at fixing your code formatting and indentation. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev thank you for the suggestion. I'll consider it for the next questions i'll ask since this one is solved.

Comment: How about fixing this one. You do realise the content you post here is  not just for your benefit but for other users who may encounter the same problem? So why not get some practice and fix this one now?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this:

```
StreamWriter file;
try
{
     file = new StreamWriter("text6.txt");
     file.Close();
}
catch(Exception)
{
     throw;
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just made a suggestion and it worked for the user. Problem?

Comment: It solved the crashing problem. Now I take more that 50 word texts and it works without crashing.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead. You only need to create your StreamWriter immediately before you use it, and wrapping it in a `using` block will ensure that the stream is disposed immediately after you're done using it.

```
    int count = 0;
    string temp = "";
    string temp2 = "";

    for (Match m = Regex.Match(str, qmatch2); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
    {
        temp = m.Value;
        temp2 = Regex.Replace(temp, qmatch2, " . ");
        str = Regex.Replace(str, temp, temp2);
    }

    if (temp.Contains(".") == false)
    {
        using (var file = new StreamWriter("text6.txt"))
        {
            file.Write("text6.txt");
            file.WriteLine(" " + temp);                    
        }
        count++;
    }
```